# Изменение формата записи QDateTime

Tags: c++, qt

На входе имею переменную QString, которая содержит в себе дату и время в виде:

```
18.11.2016 13:00:58
```

Мне нужно переформатировать эту дату и время в такой формат:

```
пт нояб. 18 15:58:06 2016
```

Пытаюсь делать так, но  в результате переменная date пустая:

```
        qDebug() << date;
        QDateTime tmp;
        tmp.fromString(date,"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        date = tmp.toString();
        qDebug() << date;
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
qDebug() << date;
QDateTime tmp;
tmp = QDateTime::fromString(date,"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
date = tmp.toString();
qDebug() << date;
```